# Migrate database from one dyno to another one

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Is there a way to transfer a postgres database from one dyno to another in heroku or do I have to make a backup, and restore?

Comment: What should be attached to the original dyno at the end of this? Should both apps see the same database? Should the original dyno have a new, empty database? Should the original have no database provisioned?